Connected to wifi but no wifi icon on taskbar
This is what I see in the Gnome taskbar:

I am connected to WiFi (I know because I can browser the internet) but I can't change networks because I have no settings on the taskbar or in my network settings:

I installed Debian without any software expect the base system.
output of iw:
$ sudo iw dev
phy#0
    Interface wlp1s0
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr a4:db:30:c7:42:cb
        type managed
        channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
        txpower 20.00 dBm


Why are you sure you are connected? How did you check? Please [edit] your question and add that, and also add the output of iw dev.

I sure connected because i can still browsing

That is weird... How did you connect? If you can't see the WiFi in the GUI, what did you use to connect?

i connect when installing the debian

but now i cant change anymore

I'm guessing your WiFi interface is currently controlled by something other than NetworkManager. Perhaps it has been configured with "plain" ifupdown or wpa-supplicant settings?  Does your /etc/network/interfaces file mention wlp1s0? Likewise any files in /etc/network/interfaces.d? Does nmcli device say that wlp1s0 is currently unmanaged?

Ah yes, wlp1s0 is unmaged
